# In T-SQL, how do you add additional text at the beginning of a field?

Tags: t-sql

In T-SQL, how do you add additional text at the beginning of a field?

Comment: Using concatenation, like every other language.

Comment: Also, SQL doesn't have "fields", it has Columns and rows

Comment: Thank you, Larnu, for commenting and for the clarification.  I wasn't sure how to talk about the records in a certain table Column.

Comment: **Rows** in a column.

Comment: I have seen the use of CONCAT to append text, so it's always after any existing text in the Column.  I'm wondering how to get text to append before any existing text in the Column records.

Comment: There's no difference in conatenation between `'a' + 'b'` and `'b' + 'a'`...

Comment: @Larnu, thank you, I understand that now.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way: `UPDATE sometable SET somecolumn = 'additional text' +  somecolumn;`

Comment: thank you.  I've combined your element with the the statement from Used_By_Already.

Answer (score 0):

[String concatenation in TSQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/string-concatenation-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is performed with the `+` operator, e.g.:

```
select 'expression1 ' + 'expression2'
```

[Alternatively](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) you may also use `concat()`

```
select concat('expression1 ','expression2')
```

You control what gets added by controlling the left to right sequence of any concatenation. i.e. these produce different results:

```
select concat('expression1 ','expression2')

select concat('expression2 ','expression1')
```

Comment: thank you.  I've combined your statement with the one from Yael into this...                                 UPDATE Vendor_Code
SET Notes_Public = CONCAT('INTERNAL REQUESTOR:        ', Notes_Public)
WHERE (Company_Code = 'ABC')
  AND (Notes_Public IS NOT NULL)

Comment: It works perfectly!  However, I noticed in testing another variation that the CONCAT appended again to the row.  i.e.  INTERNAL REQUESTOR:       INTERNAL REQUESTOR:   How do I remove text from this row?

Comment: If it is repeating the concatenation you have probably run it more than once on that/those rows, so be careful to exclude any you have  have already done by using a predicate in the where clause such as this  `AND NOT  Notes_Public LIKE 'NTERNAL REQUESTOR: %`